# Can I render a partial and return JSON in a single request?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, xmlhttprequest

What I am trying to accomplish is simple. I am using Rails and CoffeeScript (and S3).

1. User Drags a file onto a drop area for uploading.
2. CoffeeScript sends an xmlHTTP request to a Rails controller action to get a signed URL for the S3 request.
3. Rails creates a record for the upload, creates a signed request URL, and sends back a JSON object that contains the signed URL as well as an upload-id for progress events and what not.

Since I have the Rails action responding with JSON, I can't have rails also render a .js.coffee(.erb) file to update a partial containing an upload count.

Is there a convenient way to accomplish both of these tasks with a single request??

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using a js.erb, use render_to_string method for the partial and send it with the json response

Comment: I saw this method briefly, but didn't think it was what I needed.. Sure enough.. Exactly what I needed.. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

providing you want to accomplish everything with one request, you either:

- respond to the action in a js format and then write all the logic to set the JSON string in a known place/variable, update the counter, etc etc, all in one place.
- set the encoding of the XMLHttpRequest as JSON, respond to the action in JSON format with your desired JSON string, and then on the success callback of your client request update the counter on the client side. This has the advantage of "uncomplicating" the logic of your response by leaving all the computation in the hands of the end user's device.